Most cards are not displayed in button headers?
The code is working fine. Data is stored with localstroge. It can include titles and cards. Click on the title to see the cards. The problem is that when I click on the desired title, the same cards appear. I want each title to have its own cards.


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const titleForm = document.getElementById('titleForm');
        const titleCardForm = document.getElementById('titleCardForm');
        const titleInput = document.getElementById('titleInput');
        const titleCardFront = document.getElementById('titleCardFront');
        const titleCardBack = document.getElementById('titleCardBack');
        const titleInputFront = document.getElementById('titleInputFront');
        const titleInputBack = document.getElementById('titleInputBack');
        const cards = document.getElementById('cards');
        const chatList = document.getElementById('chatList');
        const playCards = document.getElementById('playCards');
        const footerButton = document.getElementById('footerButton');
        const playCardFooterButton = document.getElementById('playCardFooterButton');
        let currentTitleElement = null;
        let currentTitleCardElement = null;
        
        

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const savedTitles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('titles')) || [];
            savedTitles.forEach(title => addTitleToList(title));

            const savedCardFronts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardFronts')) || [];
            const savedCardBacks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardBacks')) || [];

            for (let i = 0; i < savedCardFronts.length; i++) {
                addCardToList(savedCardFronts[i], savedCardBacks[i]);
            }
        });


        titleForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const title = titleInput.value.trim();
            if (title) {
                addTitleToList(title);

                // Save to localStorage
                const savedTitles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('titles')) || [];
                savedTitles.push(title);
                localStorage.setItem('titles', JSON.stringify(savedTitles));

                titleInput.value = '';
                const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('exampleFooterModal'));
                modal.hide();
            }
        });
        titleCardForm.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const inputFront = titleInputFront.value.trim();
            const inputBack = titleInputBack.value.trim();
            if (inputFront && inputBack) {
                addCardToList(inputFront, inputBack);

                const savedCardFronts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardFronts')) || [];
                savedCardFronts.push(inputFront);
                localStorage.setItem('cardFronts', JSON.stringify(savedCardFronts));

                const savedCardBacks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardBacks')) || [];
                savedCardBacks.push(inputBack);
                localStorage.setItem('cardBacks', JSON.stringify(savedCardBacks));


                titleInputFront.value = ''
                titleInputBack.value = ''
                const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('exampleFooterCardModal'));
                modal.hide();
            }
        });

        function addTitleToList(title) {
            const newItem = document.createElement('button');
            newItem.className = 'list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center';
            newItem.innerHTML = `<h5 class="mb-1">${title}</h5>`;
            cards.classList.add('hidden'); 
            
            newItem.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                currentTitleElement = newItem;
                const contextModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('contextModal'));
                contextModal.show();
            });
            newItem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                cards.classList.toggle('hidden');
                chatList.style.display = 'none';
                playCardFooterButton.className = "btn btn-success rounded-circle d-block justify-content-center align-items-center shadow-lg";
            });
            chatList.appendChild(newItem);
        }
        function addCardToList(inputFront, inputBack) {
            const newCard = document.createElement('div')
            newCard.className = 'col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4'
            newCard.innerHTML = `
            <div class="flip-card mb-3" onclick="flipCard(this)">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        ${inputFront}
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        ${inputBack}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`
            newCard.addEventListener('contextmenu', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                currentTitleCardElement = newCard;
                const contextModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('contextModal'));
                contextModal.show();
            });
            cards.appendChild(newCard);
        }


        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (currentTitleElement || currentTitleCardElement) {
                let index;
                if (currentTitleElement) {
                    // 'titles' elementni o'chirish
                    const titleText = currentTitleElement.querySelector('h5').textContent;
                    const savedTitles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('titles')) || [];
                    const updatedTitles = savedTitles.filter(title => title !== titleText);
                    localStorage.setItem('titles', JSON.stringify(updatedTitles));
                    currentTitleElement.remove();
                    currentTitleElement = null;
                } else if (currentTitleCardElement) {
                    // 'cardFronts' va 'cardBacks' elementni o'chirish
                    index = Array.from(cards.children).indexOf(currentTitleCardElement);
                    currentTitleCardElement.remove();

                    const savedCardFronts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardFronts')) || [];
                    const savedCardBacks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardBacks')) || [];

                    if (index >= 0) {
                        savedCardFronts.splice(index, 1);
                        savedCardBacks.splice(index, 1);
                        localStorage.setItem('cardFronts', JSON.stringify(savedCardFronts));
                        localStorage.setItem('cardBacks', JSON.stringify(savedCardBacks));
                    }
                }

                // Modalni yopish
                const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('contextModal'));
                modal.hide();
            }
        });


        document.getElementById('editBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (currentTitleElement || currentTitleCardElement) {
                if (currentTitleElement) {
                    // 'titles'ni tahrirlash
                    const titleText = currentTitleElement.querySelector('h5').textContent;
                    const newValue = prompt("Yangi nomni kiriting:", titleText);

                    if (newValue && newValue.trim() !== "") {
                        // LocalStorage'ni yangilash
                        const savedTitles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('titles')) || [];
                        const index = savedTitles.indexOf(titleText);
                        if (index >= 0) {
                            savedTitles[index] = newValue;
                            localStorage.setItem('titles', JSON.stringify(savedTitles));

                            // DOMni real vaqt rejimida yangilash
                            currentTitleElement.querySelector('h5').textContent = newValue;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (currentTitleCardElement) {
                    const frontText = currentTitleCardElement.querySelector('.flip-card-front').textContent.trim();
                    const backText = currentTitleCardElement.querySelector('.flip-card-back').textContent.trim();
                    const newFrontValue = prompt('1', frontText)
                    const newBackValue = prompt('2', backText)

                    if (newFrontValue && newFrontValue.trim() !== "" && newBackValue && newBackValue.trim() !== "") {
                        const savedCardFronts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardFronts')) || [];
                        const indexFronts = savedCardFronts.indexOf(frontText);
                        const savedCardBacks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cardBacks')) || [];
                        const indexBacks = savedCardBacks.indexOf(backText);
                        if (indexFronts >= 0 || indexBacks >= 0) {
                            savedCardFronts[indexFronts] = newFrontValue;
                            savedCardBacks[indexBacks] = newBackValue;
                            localStorage.setItem('cardFronts', JSON.stringify(savedCardFronts))
                            localStorage.setItem('cardBacks', JSON.stringify(savedCardBacks))

                            currentTitleCardElement.querySelector('.flip-card-front').textContent = newFrontValue;
                            currentTitleCardElement.querySelector('.flip-card-back').textContent = newBackValue;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Modalni yopish
                const modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('contextModal'));
                modal.hide();
            }
        });

        
        function flipCard(card) {
            card.classList.toggle('flipped');
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .flip-card {
            height: 300px;
        }

        .flip-card-inner {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transition: transform 1s;
        }

        .flip-card.flipped .flip-card-inner {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }

        .flip-card-front,
        .flip-card-back {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
        }

        .flip-card-front {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .flip-card-back {
            background-color: #f44336;
            color: white;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Footer</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <header class="bg-primary text-white py-3 mb-4">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>My Application</h1>
            <p class="lead">Manage your titles effectively</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="container my-4">
        <div class="list-group mb-5" id="chatList">
        </div>
        <div id="playCards" class="mb-5 text-center text-success" style="font-size: 1.5rem;">
            <div class="row hidden" id="cards">
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="bg-dark text-white text-center py-3 mt-auto position-fixed w-100 bottom-0">
        <button type="button" id="footerButton"
            class="btn btn-danger rounded-circle d-block justify-content-center align-items-center shadow-lg"
            data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleFooterModal"
            style="width: 60px; height: 60px; top: -30px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); position: absolute; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;">
            +
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="playCardFooterButton"
            class="btn btn-success rounded-circle d-none justify-content-center align-items-center shadow-lg"
            data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleFooterCardModal"
            style="width: 60px; height: 60px; top: -30px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); position: absolute; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; display: none;">
            +
        </button>
    </footer>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleFooterModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleFooterModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleFooterModalLabel">Add New Title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="titleForm">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="titleInput" class="form-label">Enter Title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleInput" required>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleFooterCardModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleFooterCardModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleFooterCardModalLabel">Add New Title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="titleCardForm">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="titleInputFront" class="form-label">Enter Title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleInputFront" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="titleInputBack" class="form-label">Enter Title</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleInputBack" required>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="contextModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="contextModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="contextModalLabel">Item Actions</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button id="editBtn" class="btn btn-warning w-100 mb-2">Edit</button>
                    <button id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-danger w-100">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



I can't figure out what the problem is. I asked for help from several places but to no avail.

There is too much code here. Now that the code is displayed in a code snippet, can you edit the code so that is only includes what is necessary for showing the card-thing, and not using localstorage, now that it doesn't work on Stack Overflow.
